# Ubuntu - application-specific power management

Tags: ubuntu, power-management

I listen to lots of music while doing non-computer related stuff and my laptop falls asleep after 30 mins, as per my power settings, so I have to go back to the laptop to wiggle the mouse every now and then.

I've noticed that when Totem plays a video, it overrides the power settings - screen remains on all the time and I don't have to do anything.

Is this a specific feature of Totem, or is there any way I can do the same with my sound applications? What about, say, a Flash or HTML5 video player inside a browser?

I'm using a distro based on Ubuntu 10.10, players used are Clementine and Spotify for Linux. Totem came as default on my distro which is why I suspect it's some sort of system preset involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no "presets". Totem simply asks the GNOME session manager to temporarily disable the "session idle" check.

If your music player does not have full GNOME support (as is often the case with desktop environment-agnostic software), you will have to use an external tool; I have [written `gnome-mpris-inhibit`](https://github.com/grawity/hacks/blob/master/media/gnome-mpris-inhibit) for MPRIS v2-capable players which will inhibit idle as long as music is playing: (requires *libnet-dbus-perl*)

```
$ setsid ./gnome-mpris-inhibit clementine
$ setsid ./gnome-mpris-inhibit spotify
```

(The MPRIS bus name usually matches the program's actual name, but check using the [`mpris`](https://github.com/grawity/hacks/blob/master/media/mpris) tool just in case. The two examples above are already checked.)

For Flash, the [Caffeine](https://launchpad.net/caffeine) tool ([ppa](https://launchpad.net/~caffeine-developers/+archive/ppa)) claims to be able to detect video playback. It does not work for HTML 5 yet, though, but it *seems* to have a clickable manual activation applet. (I don't have Ubuntu so I cannot test it here.)

If all else fails, [this `gnome-inhibit` script](https://github.com/grawity/hacks/blob/master/desktop/gnome-inhibit) can be used to pause the idle check manually:

```
$ gnome-inhibit --what=idle
gnome-inhibit: pausing until signal; use Ctrl-C to interrupt
```

Update: GNOME itself now has an equivalent command:

```
$ gnome-session-inhibit --inhibit-only
Inhibiting until Ctrl+C is pressed...
```

Comment: Just tried your script - got `execvp: Permission denied
`. Running as sudo didn't really help. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably forgot to mark it as executable (`chmod +x`).

Comment: Ok, script works now. Though from the several short tests I did it seems to work only after Clementine/Spotify have launched? If so, I guess I'll need to figure out how to automate that - but that's a different question altogether. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Andrey: The latest version should deal nicely with being started before the player.

Comment: Just did a quick test with Spotify and it works perfectly - thank you so much for that script! I'll come back to upvote your answer once I have the reputation for it.

Comment: The links to scripts hosted on Github in this solution are dead.